# You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, suneditor

When i start the the react app it gives the following error. i have commented the
`export * as buttonList from './SundEditor'` from the package in node_modules then it works but i need this buttonList and react can't load it

[image: error]

```
"dependencies": {
    "@evenlogics/whf-reactadmin": "^1.1.18",
    "katex": "^0.13.11",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "suneditor": "^2.39.0",
    "suneditor-react": "^3.1.0"
},
```

Comment: How are you bundling your app? The error is saying that the bundler doesn't recognize the `export *` syntax, which likely means you need to configure babel to transpile ES6 code. You need `@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from`, but you can just install `@babel/preset-env` which includes it.

Comment: it did install ```@babel/preset-env``` but it still couldn't export it

Comment: my node_modules already have all babel packages installed.

Comment: what node version u are using?

Comment: 14.16.1
actually simple CRA these installed packages works fine... its some configuration issue with our structure just can't figure out where and how :(